# Java class method: editing an array of strings with a for loop

Tags: java

To be blunt, I was creating a class called 'Directory', which handles/offers directory operations such as reading the directory data, checking to see in a name exists in the directory in a case- independent manner, adds names to the directory, deletes names from the directory, and writes the updated directory to file Directory.txt. I'm stuck upon a method I was trying to create, which is supposed to remove an element from an array, and move all the following elements down a position. Here is my complete code for this class, the method which doesn't seem to be working properly is delete():

```
package homeworks;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Directory {
// max directory size = 1024

 final int maxDirectorySize = 1024;
 String directory[] = new String[maxDirectorySize];
 int directorySize = 0;
 File directoryFile = null;
 Scanner directoryDataIn = null;

 //constructor
 Directory(String directoryFileName) {
     directoryFile = new File(directoryFileName);

     try {
         directoryDataIn = new Scanner(directoryFile);
     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.printf("File %s not found, exiting!",directoryFileName);
         System.exit(0);
     }
     // Loading Directory
     while (directoryDataIn.hasNext()){
         directory[directorySize++] = directoryDataIn.nextLine();
     }
 }

 public boolean inDirectory(String name) {
     for(int i=0; i<directorySize; i++){
         if(directory[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
             return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
 }
 public boolean add(String name) {
    // add to directory if directory is not full
    // directory size is increased by 1
    // returns true if successful; false otherwise
     if(directorySize<maxDirectorySize){
         directory[directorySize++] = name;
         return true;
     }
     else{
         return false;
     }
 }

 public boolean delete(String name) {
     // if name is in directory, remove it and shift
     // other entries to use freed space; directory size
     // is reduced by 1
     // returns true if successful; false
     for(int i = 0; i<directorySize;){
         if(directory[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
             for(int c = i; c<directorySize+1; c++){
                 directory[c] = directory[c++];
             }
             for(int c =0; c<directorySize; c++)
                 System.out.println(directory[c]);
             return true;
         }
         i++;
     }
     return false;
 }
 public void closeDirectory() {
     directoryDataIn.close();
     for(int i = 0; i < directorySize; i++){
         System.out.println(directory[i]);
     }
     // close explicitly before writing
     PrintStream directoryDataOut = null;
     // now open the directory data file for writing
     try {
         directoryDataOut = new PrintStream(directoryFile);
     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.printf("File %s not found, exiting!", directoryFile);
         System.exit(0);
     }

     // write possibly updated directory back to file
     for (int i = 0; i < directorySize; i++)
            directoryDataOut.println(directory[i]);
            directoryDataOut.close();

 }
}
```

Another issue I had is with the last method, closeDirectory(). I was wondering how exactly you would go about checking to see if the array was changed, to see whether you have to rewrite the the file or not. I know that using 'ArrayLists' would be simpler, but I specifically must use arrays for this project. I attempted to create an array called 'originalDirectory', which is simply a replica of the array 'directory' in the constructor. However, I couldn't figure it out (I removed it afterwards).

Comment: Have you tried debugging? If you do, you'll see that the `c` variable will increment in an unexpected was in the shifting loop, if you think about it, you'll see why.

Comment: I have, by checking to see what the array directory contains several times. When I use the delete method, the array is not even changed.

Comment: Quick question; is there a particular reason foe the `i++;` line to be at the end of the for loop instead of in its declaration?

Comment: Nope, I was just testing to see whether it made a difference at all. I ended up removing it at the end and putting it back in the for loop declaration to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following code snippet looks a bit odd.

```
 for(int c = i; c<directorySize+1; c++){
     directory[c] = directory[c++];
 }
```

when you call `directory[c] = directory[c++];`, you're incrementing `c`.  You're already doing that in your for loop, so the result is that your incrementing it twice.

I don't think that you need to be doing that.

try

```
directory[c] = directory[c+1];
```

---

your loop condition:  `c<directorySize+1` also looks like it can be troublesome.  if you ever call `directory[c] = directory[c+1];` when `c` is the maximum size of your `directory` array, then you'll get an index out of bounds exception.  I understand that `directorySize` might not necessarily always be the same as `directory.length`, but you might want to have code to account for that.

Comment: I don't understand, the block of code you're telling me to try still increments    c    twice from what you said. The only change I see is with the 2nd parameter of the for loop.

Comment: @abdi it's in the content of the forloop.  I'm using `directory[c+1]` instead of  `directory[c++]`

Comment: The problem is somewhat fixed now, I didn't realize using c++ instead of c+1 would increment the variable permanently. The array does seem to be "shifted down", but now, the final element is repeated twice, making the last two elements a duplicate. Would I have to modify the second parameter to correct this?

Comment: @abdi I'm guessing that the final element of the array just didn't have anything else shifted on top of it.

Comment: @abdi  You should have the ability to figure out how to handle that on your own.  it is **your** homework afterall

Comment: I solved the problem, it was with my decremented the directorySize variable. Also, this isn't a homework assignment, just an interesting assignment I found online to practice Java. Thank you for your assistance.